# Can't get 4 circle to appear at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to have 4 colored circles to pop up when I click the mouse; however, only the last purple circle (var circle4) is the only one that appears after I clicked the mouse. With the method (shape.on("click", function()...), I am able to bring up a circle by clicking the mouse. I am trying to bring up all of them at the same time, but I only kept getting the final circle. I figured that applying the method to all of the circles would work. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>D3 Circle Split</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/d3.v3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
 var h = 2000;
 var w = 2000;
 var xGrid = 300;
 var yGrid = 300;
 var radius = 300;

 var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", h);

var shape = svg.append("circle")
             .attr("cx", xGrid)
             .attr("cy", yGrid)
             .attr("r", radius)
             .style("fill", "yellow")


shape.on("click", function(){
var circle1 = svg.append("circle")
               .attr("cx", xGrid - radius/2)
               .attr("cy", yGrid - radius/2)
               .attr("r", radius/2)
               .style("fill", "red")
          });

 shape.on("click", function(){
 var circle2 = svg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", xGrid + radius/2)
                .attr("cy", yGrid - radius/2)
                .attr("r", radius/2)
                .style("fill", "blue")
   });

  shape.on("click", function(){
  var circle3 = svg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", xGrid - radius/2)
                .attr("cy", yGrid + radius/2)
                .attr("r", radius/2)
                .style("fill", "green")
    });

   shape.on("click", function(){
   var circle4 = svg.append("circle")
               .attr("cx", xGrid + radius/2)
               .attr("cy", yGrid + radius/2)
               .attr("r", radius/2)
               .style("fill", "purple")
    });

    </script>

     </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your circles seem to have the same size and coordinates ... so, only the last one is visible, because they lie on top of each other.

Try this:

```
<script>
     var h = 2000;
     var w = 2000;
     var xGrid = 300;
     var yGrid = 300;
     var radius = 300;

     var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg").attr("width",w).attr("height",h);

     var shape = svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx",xGrid).attr("cy",yGrid).attr("r",radius).style("fill","yellow");

     shape.on("click", function(){
         var circle1 = svg.append("circle")
             .attr("cx", xGrid-radius/2)
             .attr("cy", yGrid-radius/2)
             .attr("r", (radius/2)+30)
             .style("fill", "red");
         var circle2 = svg.append("circle")
             .attr("cx", (xGrid-radius/2)+10)
             .attr("cy", (xGrid-radius/2)+10)
             .attr("r", (radius/2)+20)
             .style("fill", "blue");
         var circle3 = svg.append("circle")
             .attr("cx", (xGrid-radius/2)+20)
             .attr("cy", (xGrid-radius/2)+20)
             .attr("r", (radius/2)+10)
             .style("fill", "green");
         var circle4 = svg.append("circle")
             .attr("cx", (xGrid-radius/2)+30)
             .attr("cy", (xGrid-radius/2)+30)
             .attr("r", radius/2)
             .style("fill", "purple");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do all 4 circles at once. Also, keeping with @Ole Suffaus answer;

```
shape.on('click', function() {
    var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple'])
      .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
            return xGrid - radius / 2 + i * 10;
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d, i) {
            return yGrid - radius / 2 + i * 10;
        })
        .attr('r', radius / 2)
        .style('fill', function(d) {
            return d;
        });
});
```